# Tfs downloading files but not adding them to the project

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

I use two different pcs to work on one project and it's quite large. It has a bunch of projects inside.

One of them is a mvc web app. I never had any issues until recently (over 450 check-ins already).

When I check-in the files on my first pc everything works fine, I can see the files on tfs from both machines...

When I downloaded the latest version on the second PC everything looked like it went okay. Until I realized that while the files are downloaded to local system they aren't added to the project. But the files that need to be updated are getting updated. Any ideas?

I tried creating a new workspace but I have the same issues. I'm having problems with all sorts of files (.js, .css, images, etc.)

I'm using Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: Nevermind. I am dumb. My .csproj file was on the excluded changes list.

Answer (score 0):

You likely forgot to check in the changes to the Project in Visual Studio.

Make sure that if you are adding files that you always check in the Project file so that others can see the changes.